# CPU ordering in Linux (with hyper threading)

Tags: linux, hyperthreading

I'm curious what the CPU ordering is in Linux.  Say I bind a thread to cpu0 and another to cpu1 on a hyperthreaded system, are they both going to be on the same physical core.  Given a Core i7 920 with 4 cores and hyperthreading, the output of /proc/cpuinfo has me thinking that cpu0 and cpu1 are different physical cores, and cpu0 and cpu4 are on the same physical core.

Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

The physical cpu/socket is listed as `physical id`.
The physical core is listed as `core id`.
A processor entry due to hypherthreading will get its own `processor`, but share `core id` and `physical id` with another.

Note that each physical cpu (`physical id`) can have multiple cores (`core id`), which can further be broken up into additional logical cpus by hyperthreading. The logical cpus are overall ordered by `processor id`.

There's a detailed explanation with examples here: [archive.richweb.com/cpu_info via web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20150705000638/http://archive.richweb.com/cpu_info)

Comment: That's incorrect. 'Physical id' is a socket. He has a single socket computer with a quadcore i7 with hyperthreading. All of his cores should have 'physical id' 0. 'core id' refers to the physical cores, and he should have 0-3 of those. The logical cores are defined as 'processor' and should be numbered 0-7. ... On my system, processors 0 and 4 share the same core id, processors 1 and 5 share the same core id, etc. Just make sure you don't bind two processes to the same 'core id' unless you really want to. So processor 0 and 4 are logical cpus (hyperthreading) on the same core.

Comment: You can use `egrep "(( id|processo).*:|^ *$)" /proc/cpuinfo` to get only the relevant information from `/proc/cpuinfo`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `likwid-topology -g` to get graphical topology of the cpu. It shows each cpu primary cores along with the sibling core.

Answer (score -1):

See the pointer provided in [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/227920).  The information is all in /proc/cpuinfo with regards to physical processors, cores, and hyperthreading, but you have to match info from multiple entries in that file to identify which ones group together.